# Windows 7 freezes for 20 minutes at boot, randomly

Tags: windows-7

I have a core i3 with an ocz vertex 2 ssd that's driving me nuts.

Sometimes, at random (one in 10 boots), 30 seconds after the boot, the desktop freezes.

What's interesting is that if I turn it off, it freezes again (safe mode included): the only way to make it work again is to wait 20 minutes. After it's un frozen, it works again.

What's going on??

edit: I forgot to say that I can move around the mouse cursor, just nothing happens for 20 minutes (no, ctrl-alt-canc doesn't work)

Comment: Have you tested the RAM?

Comment: No, I didn't test

Comment: Run memtest to see if it is a RAM problem.

Comment: OCZ drives are really not recommend. My Samsung SSD 830 works fantastic. So best is to replace the ocz SSD.

Comment: Changed with an HDD and now it works much better - weird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this exact issue with that drive and it was faulty. After I had it replaced all problems went away. Basically what it came down to was when windows tried writing to a certain sector the drive stopped responding leading to a system crash.

Had the drive replaced and everything works just fine. Try booting a Linux Live-CD and test the drive.

I´d suggest you report the drive broken if you still have warranty left on it.

Comment: I replaced the drive with another ocz vertex 2 ssd and i was having the same problems (even on a clean install!). I replaced it again with an old 160gb magnetic hdd, and now it works fine.